# nginx wildcard redirect suspicious symbols warnig

Tags: nginx, redirect

I would like to create a 301 redirect on nginx to do this:

```
*.example.gr/en/* => http://www.example.gr/el/
```

I have tried to do:

```
server{
listen       80;
server_name  ~^.example.gr/en/*;
return       301 http://www.example.gr/el/;
}
```

But I cannot find the proper wildcard regex to add to the `server_name` at the server blocks as with the `"/en"` I get a suspicious symbols warning

Comment: You need to create a location /en and then in that location redirect to new host... you cant create server nema like domain.com/something, you only can create server_name domain.com and then you need to create a location /someting and working in that location for redirects etc.. check here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html

Comment: Post your complete nginx configuration, a proper configuration cannot be written without seeing the complete configuration.

Answer (score 2):

You won't match URIs in the server_name directive as it's ... for server names.

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name *.example.gr;

    location /en {
        return 301 http://www.example.gr/el/;
    }

}


server {

    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.gr;

    location /el {
        # Your stuff
    }

}
```

For the record, Nginx server name choosing order is :

1. Exact name
2. Longest name with a leading wildcard
3. Longest name with a trailing wildcard
4. First matching regular expression